# How do you escape curly braces in javadoc inline tags, such as the {@code} tag

Tags: java, javadoc, escaping, curly-braces

```
/**
 * Gets the meatball icon for a nincompoop.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Example: {@code <custom:meatball color="<%= Meatball.RED %> nincompoop="${person}" />}
 * 
 * @author King Cong
 * 
 */
```

The "${person}" part breaks the doc comment because it uses curly braces.

Comment: It's even worse with `{@link ...}` which is transformed to an `<a href="...">...</a>`. For a use case see [correctly render javadoc method links to external html javadoc documents that use dashes instead of parentheses and commas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69248525/1744774).

Answer (score 29):

Not so much an answer as a workaround, but if you replace `{@code ...}` with the old version `<code>...</code>` it will render curly braces how you expect.

```
<code>{person} == ${person}</code>
```

Unfortunately, this breaks angle brackets, so to the original question you need to escape these:

```
<code>&lt;custom:meatball color="&lt;%= Meatball.RED %&gt; nincompoop="${person}" /&gt;</code>
```

You can even cheat here by getting Notepad++ to do that for you, with the handy TextFX -> convert -> Encode HTML (&<>").

This does at least have the benefit that everything renders nicely both in the generated Javadoc and in Eclipse in the Javadoc view, which doesn't appear to understand `&#125;` and friends.

Answer (score 24):

Try using HTML escapes:

```
$&#123;person&#125; == ${person}
```

Comment: Sad that that is the best answer.

Comment: It's rather annoying, isn't it? I wish there were a better way.

Comment: Seems not to be rendered correctly in the Eclipse Javadoc View.

Comment: Does this really work as expected? Documentation says that stuff inside `{@code}` is *not* interpreted as HTML, just like `{@literal}`, so that'd be reason to suspect that character references won't work either.

Comment: I ended up with using HTML escapes, without the `{@code}` tag. it rendered by IDEs as readable anyway. Also use of `<code></code>` would make markup better.

Answer (score 9):

bodunbodun solution works as it usually happens that you have newline as well in the javadocs. HTML escapes won't work if you want both { and newline

```
<pre>
{@code
<foo bar="}${bar}{@code"/>
<bar foo="}${foo}{@code"/>
}
</pre>
```

will give you

```
<foo bar="${bar}" />
<bar foo="${foo}" />
```

Comment: Gets my vote when I want to keep space-formatting as in my comment, keep the angled brackets and show ${...} as in demonstrating maven plugin config (properties). It muddies the comment a little but to the advantage of the javadoc output (and eclipse javadoc highlighting). Guess it's where you prefer to be prettier - comment or javadoc - though it's a small loss of clarity.

Comment: Sadly as of JDK 1.8 + Eclipse Neon, the strict javadoc checker will complain that a closing brace of `@code` is missing. So I went to using  `<pre><code/></pre>` again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem actually - none of propositions have worked for me (HTML escapes do not work for whatever reason).
If that helps - try closing the {@code} before problematic symbol and reopen it after, like this:

{@code  nincompoop="**}${person}{@code**" />}

This doesn't seem the solution, but it works, and does not break formatting if used carefully :)

Comment: Ah, this one is earlier than my above upvote for arasul's answer. arasul still addresses the good use of {@code} and <pre> in achieving decent XML in javadoc and comments.

Answer (score 3):

At least as of Java 1.8.0_31, I can't reproduce the issue anymore. Your input renders as expected:

```
<code>&lt;custom:meatball color="&lt;%= Meatball.RED %&gt; nincompoop="${person}" /&gt;</code>
```

My tests indicate that `javadoc` takes into consideration balanced curly braces inside `@code`, and only ends it when the corresponding curly brace is found.

So if the code has balanced curly braces `{}` like your example, it now works as expected.

But I still don't know what to do with unbalanced curly braces like:

```
{@code printf"}<b>outside</b>"}
```

Also, the behavior depends on which inline tag you are using. `man javadoc` explicitly says that for `@link`:

```
If you need to use the right brace (}) inside the label, then use the HTML entity notation &#125;.
```

So in that case it is impossible to do any better.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a similar quote for `@code` which backs my experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Found another less than stellar workaround for this. Is it better or worse than the other ones? I'll let you decide. Take the `{@code }` part and replace it with `<code> </code>`. (This makes it all disappear because of the angle braces.) The take the very first `<` and wrap it in `{@literal }`, making it look like this `{@literal<}`. Now everything will show up fine, and it's not too horribly slaughtered in the code. The final result looks like this

```
/**
 * Gets the meatball icon for a nincompoop.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Example: <code>{@literal<}custom:meatball color="<%= Meatball.RED %> nincompoop="${person}" /></code>
 * 
 * @author King Cong
 * 
 */
```

Alternatively, if you don't like the `{@literal<}`, then you could use `&lt;` instead. The result would look like this:

```
/**
 * Gets the meatball icon for a nincompoop.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Example: <code> &lt;custom:meatball color="<%= Meatball.RED %> nincompoop="${person}" /></code>
 * 
 * @author King Cong
 * 
 */
```

Neither are great solutions, but they do work.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `{@literal}`, so do this `{@literal } }`. Works in my tests.

So for your case, it would look like this:

```
/**
 * Gets the meatball icon for a nincompoop.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Example: {@code <custom:meatball color="<%= Meatball.RED %> nincompoop="${person{@literal } }" />}
 * 
 * @author King Cong
 * 
 */
```

Comment: And apparently I didn't test enough. It doesn't play nice with the angle brackets that are also in the block.

Comment: It doesn't work at all for me.  The first } closes the { before the @literal.